# Bake textures in Cloud rendering service

Tags: textures, blender, 3dsmax

For getting realistic look in games we need to bake textures in 3DS Max and Blender. We do this on our local computers.

There are lots of Cloud Rendering services that could **render** images and save time.

Is there any cloud service that could help us **bake** textures for individual objects in the scene.

Blender or 3DS Max, any of these would fit our use case.

Comment: Don't think there are any. Texture baking isn't something that is set to be distributed across multiple machines, so the overhead of uploading the blend and downloading the result would outway any benefits you may get from a remote bake. Normally texture baking is done before sending to a render farm.

Answer (score 1):

Texture baking in 3ds Max is referred to as Render-to-Texture, or RTT.  The network rendering system is called Backburner.  And RTT renders are indeed supported with Backburner. However, you need to provide your own render farm, and Backburner setup is a different topic.  The RTT process also has a learning curve.  See documentation for [backburner](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-FC817364-656D-41F8-A13F-2C3D20612C6F.htm,topicNumber=d30e451612) and [RTT](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-76F1E8AE-9E8F-40A7-A948-471D17E09DA9.htm,topicNumber=d30e439301).

Autodesk has started promoting a new cloud application service (since about 2016) called Forge, in which vendors can create custom cloud processing apps and offer automation services like texture baking or geometry processing.  A hypothetical example is an app which creates walkthough videos given an architectural scene.  Forge processing is performed on Autodesk's own cloud machines.  There might already be a vendor providing what you need.  Repost with the following tags to get the attention of somebody from Autodesk:  forge autodesk autodesk-forge autodesk-bim360

Comment: We tried looking for vendors for our project, but none was providing such a service. Finally we went with creating automation script in Blender Python API and setup our texture baking setup on AWS GPU instances.

Comment: @ManmohanBishnoi could you be so kind to write the process and python api commands you used to back textures? Thanks

Comment: @user969068 the script we used was for blender 2.7 and is not at all compatible with Blender 2.8x or 2.9x